# Parse.com Returns null for object

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to fetch object from parse.com. But I get an empty object.Here is the class.

[image: Screenshot]

And here is my code.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AppDate");
    query.getInBackground("lOtmkstVaR", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("DATA", object.getObjectId());
            } else {
                // something went wrong
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is my logcat.

```
06-12 10:57:20.203    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseException: no results found for query
06-12 10:57:20.273    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.AbstractParseQueryController$1.then(AbstractParseQueryController.java:26)
06-12 10:57:20.273    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.AbstractParseQueryController$1.then(AbstractParseQueryController.java:17)
06-12 10:57:20.273    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$13.run(Task.java:755)
06-12 10:57:20.273    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
06-12 10:57:20.273    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:746)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:31)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$9.then(Task.java:538)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$9.then(Task.java:535)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:832)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:31)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:887)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:921)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14$1.then(Task.java:813)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14$1.then(Task.java:800)
06-12 10:57:20.274    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$13.run(Task.java:755)
06-12 10:57:20.275    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
06-12 10:57:20.275    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:746)
06-12 10:57:20.275    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:545)
06-12 10:57:20.275    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:556)
06-12 10:57:20.275    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:800)
06-12 10:57:20.275    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-12 10:57:20.275    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-12 10:57:20.275    7512-7512/com.andromedatech.onlineradio W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I just started using parse.com back-end service. I am using parse.com guide.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a simple typo in your query. Your class name is `AppData` but you have used `AppDate`. It should be

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AppData");
```

Comment: I changed it. Still I get no object

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too. Is caused by parse don't return a "ParseObject", just and object, here my code which works fine for me:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Your_class_name");
query.getInBackground(imagenID, new GetCallback() {

@Override
                            public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {
                            ParseObject object = (ParseObject) o;
                            ParseFile foto = (ParseFile) object.get("Your_column_name");
                            foto.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        //do your things like decoding to a Bitmap
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        e.printStacktrace();

                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                   }
```

just replace your "done" for my "done". It works perfectly for me

Comment: For this code I get following error. Error:(87, 63) error: <anonymous com.andromedatech.onlineradio.MainActivity$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method done(Object,Throwable) in ParseCallback2

Comment: Did you replace the query too?